# How to delete a Google Search Console property

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

Is it possible to remove a property from Google Search Console?

Comment: Why are you going to remove a property from google search console? Once you add google search console property, google recognizes your seo site although you remove a property.

Comment: @seopine, for switching from ["Url Prefix" property to "Domain property"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592), by example.
There is no point in keeping the old prefix one if it is covered by the domain one.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can remove a property from Google Search Console:

1. Manage property
2. Delete property

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the new Search Console interface, the steps are :

## Step 1 : Click on settings menu (red point)

[image]

## Step 2 : Click on "Remove Property"

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this removes the property from the account, but does not delete it. Other accounts having access to it will still have it. It may still be associated with other Google services (like Google Analytics) and may still cause troubles, or even security issues (due to other accounts accesses left on it).